# Disable particular color in JColorChooser in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jcolorchooser

I am using two `JColorChooser` dialog in my application.

To change label's:

1. Foreground Color
2. Background Color

So whatever color I have selected for foreground it should not be available in 
for background `JColorChooser`

For example,
If I choose RED color from foreground `JColorChooser` dialog , then
In background `JColorChooser` RED color should be disabled or should not be visible.

And vice versa.

So how can I implement this?

Comment: I think rather than trying to disable the color why don't you check whether the selected color == foreground/background color and if so tell user that it is not allowed?

Comment: depends of how (especially and if) is added JColorChooser to container, if yes (e.g. to JPanel) then matrix of colors is accessible programatically,

Comment: How close may permitted shades be?

Comment: *"So whatever color I have selected for foreground it should not be available in for background"*  But the other 16,777,215 solid colors are OK?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes other colors are ok.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne I know this but I don't want to control this by using if condition.

Comment: @trashgod all shades are permitted I just want to disable only one color.

Comment: @mKorbel JColorChooser is added using JDialog and I don't want to control this programatically.

Comment: @Kanti: In this scheme, `0xffff0000` and `0xfffe0000` would be acceptable but otherwise indistinguishable by humans.

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for suggestions. I know this, but If I get the solution then after I can improve this case also.

Comment: You'll likely need a [custom file chooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Comment: @trashgod Here We are talking about Color Chooser, and I don't want to create custom color chooser.

Comment: Assuming some suitable definition of _matching_, either write a custom chooser or highlight the problem once a matching color is chosen.